# System.OutOfMemoryException since WIndows IoT Core build 10.0.17763.737

Tags: c#, uwp, out-of-memory, win-universal-app, dragonboard

My c# UWP app is running on Windows IoT Core (Dragonboard 410c). Inside my app i have a simple exception logger, for finding problems in my Code, because the Project is a larger one. Since i got the update to build 10.0.17763.737, i get a System.OutOfMemoryException every few days. What can i do at best?

Comment: You're confident this is a build specific bug? Is the system actually running out of memory?

Comment: I suspect you'll learn a lot more if you use the VS Memory Profiler tooling. Alternately, if you can collect a crash dump that could help you figure out what's using all the memory. At that point you can determine if it's a tooling issue or something you can work around. That's how I'd approach the issue.

Comment: @Zakk Diaz, i think so, the build before didn't had that issue, since then i have not updated the app.

Comment: @Matt Whilden MSFT, how do i do collect a crash dump correctly? The device is running 24/7, so it is hard to tell when the Problem does occur. Some Kind of logger, which does work on the release version would be great for me.

Comment: I don't have much experience with IoT things but is seems like you should be able to collect a dump of a running process OR add automatic crash dump collection from the device portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/DevicePortal

Comment: When i have the crash dump file, how can i inspect it to find the issue?

Comment: You can watch these two videos(https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside/C000027B and https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/DefragTools-136-Debugging-User-Mode-Crash-Dumps-Part-2). They talk about how to see the dump file.